# Gpo block all website and allow only certain

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm looking for a way to block all website with GPOs and allow mannually some website like basic research on [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Google's not gonna be super useful if you can't click any of the links.

Comment: that's what I want.
I need to my users to not acess on links on google but can research some words etc. on it.

Comment: then put a firewall on the edge of your network, you don't need GPO to do this.

Comment: Group Policy isn't the right tool for this. Use your firewall for this.

Comment: Can I use firewall rules in one OU only? – 
or can we use Microsoft AntiVirus to block WebSite Access?

Answer (score 1):

In general you will find that people use a completely different approach to restrict internet access, as AFAIK even if GPO's with allow/block lists can be set up, those will then only work for specific applications (the GPO for Internet Explorer won't work for Chrome, powershell code, or Firefox for example) and such GPO's are therefore both easily circumvented and a PITA to maintain.

The usual approach is:

- install a proxy server (with authentication and here you will enforce your access policies)
- block all direct internet access from desktops/servers at the network level
- only permit internet access through the proxy server
- use a GPO to set the proxy in network settings

Comment: Can we block website access with Microsoft AntiVirus ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-design-guide suggests that Windows Defender can *"control what network traffic the device is allowed to send to the network"*  and has GPO support. No idea if that is fit for purpose, you'd have to experiment.