# GPO is there a way to block all downloads from any browsers?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm looking for a rule in GPO to block user to make any downloads from any browsers?

Is it a way to realize that?

Comment: No. While some browsers support group policies, some don't. People could also just use something other than a browser to download files. Trying to prevent this is pointless.

Comment: thanks fo your anwer. is there any other way ? firewall ? anti-virus ?

Comment: What [business] Problem are you trying to solve?  
Blocking downloads was a possible /solution/ - what are you trying to /achieve/?

Comment: Please try to avoid asking more or less the same question again and [again](https://serverfault.com/questions/1099951/gpo-block-all-website-and-allow-only-certain) as answers will more or less the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no.

*If* you control which browsers and other software that users can run *and* those browsers/software support group policies entirely, *then* you can block downloads (ie. specific content types, especially executables, possibly hidden in archives). However, many browsers and other applications don't support such policies. Users could e.g. run Powershell's `Invoke-Webrequest`, ie. they don't require optional software.

So, what you should consider is a **firewall** capable of filtering by content type. Archives (.zip, .7z, ...) are a special challenge that you need to handle as well. Note that product recommendations are explictly off-topic here.